# PHP how to echo array values which have no name attached to them

Tags: php, arrays

How can I put each value into a variable?
I tried using `foreach` but I am not sure what to put in the ??? area

I tried also using `echo $results[14]`, but I received an undefined error.

```
foreach($results['ups'] as $result) {
    echo $result['???']. '<br>';
}
```

output:

```
array(1) {
    ["ups"]=> array(4) {
        [14]=> string(5) "62.89"
        ["01"]=> string(5) "30.47"
        ["02"]=> string(5) "20.76"
        [11]=> string(5) "20.96"
    }
}
```

---

```
Array
(
    [ups] => Array
        (
            [14] => 62.89
            [01] => 30.47
            [02] => 20.76
            [11] => 20.96
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put nothing in the []:

```
foreach($results['ups'] as $result) {
    echo $result + '<br>';
}
```

should do it.

[array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) should return all defined keys, so try eg.

```
$keys = array_keys($results['ups']);
echo $results['ups'][$keys[0]];
echo $results['ups'][$keys[1]];
```

to access the first and second element.

Comment: how can I get just the first result or just the second result?

Comment: Updated the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```
    echo $results['ups']['14'];
```

if you don't know the index that you want to access or maintaining key index is not relevant.

```
sort $results['ups'];
echo $results['ups'][0];
```